# How to combine numbers into a unique sum

Tags: c#, algorithm

I can't remember the name of this, but I remember seeing this once.
I need to sum a sequence:

```
2:hand 
5:leg 
13:head
```

into one num like 7.

Then when I get 7, I know that it is hand+leg. If I get 20, I know that it is hand+leg+head.

What is the name of this technique?

Comment: 13 could be a head or 4 hands and a leg. I think you want to be using powers of two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean a [Flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) enumeration?

```
[Flags]
enum Parts
{
    Hand = 1,
    Leg = 2,
    Head = 4,
}
```

*Example:*

```
Parts p = Parts.Hand | Parts.Leg;

bool isHand = (p & Parts.Hand) != 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about a bit mask and is typically implemented using an enum decorated with the [[FlagsAttribute]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx). The values would be powers of two.

See the following SO answer for an explanation of using the [FlagsAttribute] in C#.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3261485/444610

Answer (score 1):

This is the [subset-sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).