# Comparing a single array against multiple different arays

Tags: c#, process, switch-statement, logic, affinity

For a small project on `processor affinity`, I want to create a simpler method than just a bunch of `if(lvProcessors.Items[0].Checked == true && lvProcessors.Items[1] == true etc)` comparing their exact values to see which code needs to be transferred to an `(IntPtr)`.

To make the code slightly more efficiënt, I would like to compare an array containing `booleans`, to at least 14 other arrays containing `booleans`.

Example code:

```
        var CheckState = new[] { lvProcessors.Items[0].Checked, lvProcessors.Items[1].Checked, lvProcessors.Items[2].Checked, lvProcessors.Items[3].Checked };
        //setcore1 == 1, setcore2 == 2, etc
        var SetCore1 = new[] { true, false,false,false };
        var SetCore2 = new[] { true, true, false, false };
        var SetCore3 = new[] { false, true, false, false };
        var SetCore4 = new[] { true, false, true, false };
        var SetCore5 = new[] { false, true, true, false };
        var SetCore6 = new[] { true, true, true, false };
        var SetCore7 = new[] { false, false, false, true };
        var SetCore8 = new[] { true, false, false, true };
        var SetCore9 = new[] { false, true, false, true };
        var SetCore10 = new[] { true, true, false, true };
        var SetCore11 = new[] { false, false, true, true };
        var SetCore12 = new[] { true, false, true, true };
        var SetCore13 = new[] { false, true, true, true };
        var SetCore14 = new[] { true, true, true, true };
        int switchcounter = 1;

        switch (switchcounter)
        {
            case 15:
                break;
            default:

                if (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(CheckState,<insertdynamicarrayname))
                {
                    AffinityState = (IntPtr)switchcounter;
                }
                else
                {
                    switchcounter++;
                    goto default;
                }
                break;
        }
```

So if the first `checkbox` in the `listview lvProcessors` is checked, the `var CheckState` will generate an array containing `{ true, false,false,false }`

This in turn must be compared to one of the `SetCore` arrays, and will in this case cause a match with `SetCore1`.

So what I would like to know is; how can I create a dynamic arrayname, based on the `switchcounter` on the code, that will fuse `"SetCore"` and `switchcounter.ToString()`, thus creating `SetCore1, SetCore2, SetCore3, etc`.

[EDIT]

As suggested by @Luaan, I've implemented his code to what I would've like it to be:

```
        var SetCore1 = new[] { true, false, false, false};
        [..]
        var SetCore15 = new[] { true, true, true, true };
        var allSets = new [] { SetCore1, SetCore2, SetCore3,SetCore4,SetCore5,SetCore6,SetCore7,SetCore8,SetCore9,SetCore10,SetCore11,SetCore12,SetCore13,SetCore14,SetCore15 };

        foreach (var set in allSets)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(counter.ToString());
            if (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(set, CheckState))
            {
                AffinityState = (IntPtr)counter;
                break;
            }
            else if (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(set, CheckState) == false) 
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        EditProcess.ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)AffinityState;
```

In this code, depending on the input of the `listviewcheckboxes`, it will match the depending result to a `SetCore` and using the `counter` it will give the proper `int` which is converted at the end of the `foreach` loop and set the very specific cores(i.e. 1, 2 or 0, 2, 3, etc) to be used for the selected `process` which has been selected earlier in the code(not visible).

Thanks for the suggestion on bitmasks, they look useful, but currently I have no idea how to implement them without taking half my application apart.

Comment: A [bitmask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261451/using-a-bitmask-in-c-sharp) is often a more flexible way of storing boolean combinations.

Comment: Have you tried using a 2-dimensional array?

Answer (score 0):

Just make an array of arrays:

```
var allSets = new [][] { SetCore1, SetCore2, SetCore3, ... }
```

Then you can use a simple for cycle:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allSets.Length; i++)
   HandleSet(allSets[i]);
```

Using `Enumerable.SequenceEqual` is going to be a bit slow. If you care about performance (I don't think you necessarily do in a case like this), have a look at `BitArray` - it's much smaller in memory, and the match is mostly a simple bitmasking.

**EDIT:**

If you want to convert between a `bool[]` and `int` (or `byte`, whatever you need), you can use something like this:

```
public bool[] ToBoolArray(int val)
{
  var bits = new bool[sizeof(int) * 8];

  for (var i = 0; i < bits.Length; i++)
  {
    bits[i] = (val & (1 << i)) > 0;
  }

  return bits;
}

public int ToInt32(bool[] bits)
{
  var output = default(int);

  for (var i = 0; i < bits.Length; i++)
  {
    output |= bits[i] ? 1 << i : 0;
  }

  return output;
}
```

This avoids having to deal with tons of annoying strings. Using a `BitArray` this is even simpler - creating a `BitArray` from `int` is trivial (there's a constructor), and changing it back to `int` can be done easily as above, just use `bits.Get(i)` instead of `bits[i]`.

Or even better, make your own class for handling this:

```
public sealed class CpuMask
{
  private int _bits;

  public bool this[int index]
  {
    get { return (_bits & (1 << index)) > 0; }
    set { if (value) _bits |= (1 << index); else _bits &= ~(1 << index); }
  }

  public CpuMask(int mask)
  {
    _bits = mask;
  }

  public CpuMask(IntPtr mask) : this(mask.ToInt32()) { }

  public IntPtr ToIntPtr() { return new IntPtr(_bits); }
}
```

Comment: This was actually what I was looking for, the problem is that the input is very exact for the output.
For example, `SetCore1` would result in a core affinity the same as Windows Task Manager would display. So that's only Core0. If the value would be bigger than the amount of cores, the `intptr` would be massively confused. Matching `listviewcheckboxes` to an external source which is only accessible in it's own language, is quite difficult.

Comment: @BRO_THOM You can always use wrapper classes to help you handle the mapping details. And don't worry too much about the `BitArray`s - they are pretty much designed for what you're doing, but it's not a big deal. You could even use simple `long`s for the whole affinity mask, it's not all that much more work than accessing an array (and you usually will not need to access the mask bit by bit).

Comment: I've actually been bold enough to look througha couple of methods, and the one I found most useful is like such; the array `CheckState`'s value will be converted into Bytes using `Convert.ToByte` filling a `List<string>` (creating 00001111 for example), which will be converted into a decimal in a `for` loop, causing false false false false true true true true to be converted into the decimal 15, which is what I needed.