# What work Bitmask at C#

Tags: c#, bitmask

I am trying to deal with a bit mask:

```
Mask |= 1 << MapID;
```

anybody can explain how it works?
Thanks for help guys

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261451/using-a-bitmask-in-c-sharp)

Comment: If you want to understand what that line does exactly, refer to the MSDN operators explanations: [OR assignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx) and [Bitwise left-shift](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w.aspx)

Comment: A byte is hex like 0xAB so you mask is doing a OR function 0xAB |  0x01.  You code has |= which is equivalent to Mask = Mask | 1.  You are shifting the mask by MapID so if MapID = 4, then 0x01 << 4 = 0x10