# In ASP.NET Web API, deserialization to enum doesn't work as expected

Tags: asp.net-web-api, enums, deserialization

Here is a sample of basic web API:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public MyEnum Get()
    {
        return MyEnum.One;
    }

    public void Post(MyEnum value)
    {
    }

    public void Put(int value)
    {
    }
}

public enum MyEnum
{
    One = 1,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five
}
```

Here are the queries with an expected behavior:

- POST `/api/My?value=1` → 200
- PUT `/api/My?value=1` → 200
- PUT `/api/My?value=1,2` → 400

Here is the query with an unexpected behavior:

- POST `/api/My?value=1,2` → 200 with value = 3

I don't understand why.
I expected an 400 error but I get a 200 with a wrong value.
Could someone explain me why I get this result?

Comment: A comma is not really a good way to distinguish different parameters. I think it just tries to use it as one number. Even though 3 is a mistery to me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice for passing enum params in Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39789818/best-practice-for-passing-enum-params-in-web-api)