# How to call controllers with Enum parameter from angular

Tags: c#, angular, api, enums

I my backend C Sharp API, I have the below Post controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> UploadItem(SupplierType supplierType)
{
...
}
```

SupplierType is an Enum:

```
public enum SupplierType
{
    Local,
    International,
    Own
}
```

In my front-end, I call the controller api as below:

```
  UploadData(supplier: string): Observable<boolean> {
    const httpOptions: { headers: HttpHeaders } = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) };
    return this.http.post<boolean>(`localhost/UploadItem`, supplier, httpOptions);
  }
```

The upload data method takes the value from a ng-select component and passes a string with value "0","1","2" as value.

But my controller is not being invoked. Is there a specific way to invoke controllers with enum parameter from angular?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best practice for passing enum params in Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39789818/best-practice-for-passing-enum-params-in-web-api)

Comment: Are you subscribing to UploadData? Request only gets fired upon subscription.

Comment: which port your api is running. define your port in http.post command like ('localhoost:80/UploadItem')

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm Thanks. It gets triggered after adding the Subscribe. However it is always sending the first value in the enum no matter what I send.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to add FromBody in the param:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> UploadItem([FromBody] SupplierType supplierType)
```