# Is there any way to convert a sum of numbers back to enum?

Tags: c#, api, enums, calculation

So there are some mods in a game called osu and when I call the api for any plays I get back a sum of the mod's number (like 72). However, I can't think of any way to convert that back to the original enum names.

I tried this way: `(Mods)enabled_mods`, but this only turned back the number.

```
     enum Mods
     {
         None = 0,
         NoFail = 1,
         Easy = 2,
         TouchDevice = 4,
         Hidden = 8,
         HardRock = 16,
         SuddenDeath = 32,
         DoubleTime = 64,
         Relax = 128,
         HalfTime = 256,
         Nightcore = 512, // Only set along with DoubleTime. i.e: NC only gives 576
         Flashlight = 1024,
         Autoplay = 2048,
         SpunOut = 4096,
         Relax2 = 8192,    // Autopilot
         Perfect = 16384, // Only set along with SuddenDeath. i.e: PF only gives 16416  
         Key4 = 32768,
         Key5 = 65536,
         Key6 = 131072,
         Key7 = 262144,
         Key8 = 524288,
         FadeIn = 1048576,
         Random = 2097152,
         Cinema = 4194304,
         Target = 8388608,
         Key9 = 16777216,
         KeyCoop = 33554432,
         Key1 = 67108864,
         Key3 = 134217728,
         Key2 = 268435456,
         ScoreV2 = 536870912,
         LastMod = 1073741824,
         KeyMod = Key1 | Key2 | Key3 | Key4 | Key5 | Key6 | Key7 | Key8 | Key9 | KeyCoop,
         FreeModAllowed = NoFail | Easy | Hidden | HardRock | SuddenDeath | Flashlight | FadeIn | Relax | Relax2 | SpunOut | KeyMod,
         ScoreIncreaseMods = Hidden | HardRock | DoubleTime | Flashlight | FadeIn
     }
```

I want to get the name of the values that has been summed, like if I have 72 I should get HiddenDoubleTime.

Comment: Sounds like a bitmask to me. There is a good Q&A [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261451/using-a-bitmask-in-c-sharp) that is worth checking out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you could do this:

```
Mods selectedMods = (Mods)72;

var individualMods = Enum
    .GetValues(typeof(Mods))
    .Cast<Mods>()
    .Where(mod => selectedMods.HasFlag(mod) && mod != Mods.None)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Adding to this: OP may want the string to be concatenated as 'HiddenDoubleTime', in which case I would add this `string.Concat(individualMods)`

Comment: Thank you very much! I couldn't have done this with my level of knowledge!