# TaskContinuationOptions combinations

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, akka.net

When I was looked at asynchronous pattern [PipeTo for Akka.NET](https://github.com/petabridge/akkadotnet-code-samples/blob/master/PipeTo/src/PipeTo.App/Actors/HttpDownloaderActor.cs#L98) I found example where author uses TaskContinuationOptions and operator &. Is it an erorr or may be it is a propper way to use '&' with Akka.NET and a PipeTo?

For better explain:
AttachedToParent & ExecuteSynchronously gave 0 and the inner lambda would be invoked as asyncronosly task.

[TaskContinuationOptions.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/CodeContracts/blob/master/Microsoft.Research/Contracts/MsCorlib/System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuationOptions.cs)

> /// When no continuation options are specified, specifies that default behavior 
>   should be used when executing a continuation. The continuation runs asynchronously when the antecedent task completes, regardless of the antecedent's final  property value. It the continuation is a child task, it is created as a detached nested task.

```
None = 0,
AttachedToParent = 4,
ExecuteSynchronously = 524288, // 0x00080000
```

The question should be there "&" or "|" operator?

Comment: These are bitwise operators that can be applied to enums like these. The keyword you're looking for is something like "enum bit flags" or "bitmask". Here's some documentation: [enum types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum) [bitmasks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3261485/12258072) Don't confuse `&` (bitwise and) with `&&` (logical and) and the likes. To answer the question (& or |): **usually** | is to have multiple flags and & is to check for a specific flag.

Comment: Since `AttachedToParent` and `ExecuteSynchronously` have no bits in common, it does look like the intention was to use `|` and not `&`

Comment: As an aside: you can use https://referencesource.microsoft.com to browse the .NET Framework source, and https://source.dot.net to browse the .NET Core source.

Comment: Right, using & makes little sense since that always produces 0 (aka None).  Use the Issues section to make the author aware of this.

Comment: I wrote the sample code the author is linking to - this is a bug in a ~5 year old code sample, not any of the Akka.NET libraries. But I'll go fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

Yes. The author should have used `|` instead of `&`.

**LONG ANSWER:**

Bitwise AND => The resulting bit is 1 only if both compared bits are 1.
Bitwise OR => The resulting bit is 1 if any of the two compared bits is 1.

So you first want to translate the numbers to binary (I'll add some 0's to make the comparison easier):

- 000000 : 00000000000000000000 (`None`)
- 000001 : 00000000000000000001 (`PreferFairness`)
- 000002 : 00000000000000000010 (`LongRunning`)
- 000004 : 00000000000000000100 (`AttachedToParent`)
- 065536 : 00010000000000000000 (`NotOnRanToCompletion`)
- 131072 : 00100000000000000000 (`NotOnFaulted`)
- 196608 : 00110000000000000000 (`OnlyOnCanceled`)
- 262144 : 01000000000000000000 (`NotOnCanceled`)
- 327680 : 01010000000000000000 (`OnlyOnFaulted`)
- 393216 : 01100000000000000000 (`OnlyOnFaulted`)
- 524288 : 10000000000000000000 (`ExecuteSynchronously`)

Now you know, for example, that `OnlyOnCanceled` is the same as `NotOnFaulted`+ `NotOnRanToCompletion`.
Or, using bitwise operators: `NotOnFaulted | NotOnRanToCompletion`.

On the other hand `NotOnFaulted & NotOnRanToCompletion` is equal to `0`, that corresponds to `None`.
While `OnlyOnCanceled & NotOnFaulted == NotOnRanToCompletion`.

So the answer is: when you want to combine, use `|`. When you want to get the difference, use `&`.

I hope this example made it clearer.

Comment: That is not his question. The question is if the author of the AkkaDotNet library made a mistake by using `&` to combine two enum flags that have no bits in common and that it really should've been a `|`.

Comment: It is a common mistake because people tend to think "I'll use flag X and Y".

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen as he asked the question I assumed that he didn't know what was happening. I added a TL;DR section.