# How to read and show bit 3 from Binary 8 bit textbox data?

Tags: c#

I have this in hex: 08 Which is this in binary: `0000 1000` (bit positions: 7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0)

Now I would like to make a bitmask in C# , so I have bit position 3.
Here in example 1 or better (the one in ""): `0000 "1"000`

How to show only bit3 in TextBox.text

Thanks
Mano.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a bitmask in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261451/using-a-bitmask-in-c-sharp)

Comment: `int bit3 = (source >> 3) & 1;` you'll get either `0` or `1`

Comment: Could you provide some examples, please? Suppose you have, say, `source == 1234`; what `TextBox3.Text` should have then?

Comment: txtData.Text = Convert.ToString(data, 2).PadLeft(8, '0' );

Comment: now i used  txtData.Text = Convert.ToString(data, 2).PadLeft(8, '0' );  the output show "0000 1000"  , I need to  show only bit 3 .   Please advise.

Comment: I would create an enumeration so the string name of the bit can be shown in the textbox.